# MySQL myisam dynamic tables and CHAR types

Tags: mysql, dynamic, char, myisam

From the MySQL manuals I gathered that when there are VARCHAR columns in a myisam table, then the dynamic storage format will be used. However, It wasn't clear to me, if a CHAR column in the dynamic format will be handled like a VARCHAR or if it will still be fixed size (and get the performance benefits associated with that)?

I remember from some database lectures is, that variable length data is generally appended at the end of a row's fixed length data. Part of the fixed length data would be a pointer for each VARCHAR to that data. But maybe myisam doesn't work this way. So my question is: will CHAR use such a pointer or is it stored at a fixed offset so access to it is fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be fixed to the length that you have declared when you created the table -> [MySQL dynamic format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/dynamic-format.html)

Check this question also [MySQL Row Format: Difference between fixed and dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147315/mysql-row-format-difference-between-fixed-and-dynamic)

Comment: What you mean by fixed? Maybe I don't fully understand the myisam format, but what I remember from some database lectures is, that variable length fields are generally stored using pointers at the end of a row. So the question is: will char use such a pointer or is it stored at a fixed offset?

Comment: By fixed mean that for this column there will be a fixed length place reserved. The column has a fixed length and MySQL knows that. If it was a VARCHAR for instance the column in the row will have floating/changable length depending on the content in it.