# Choose an index for mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

**The table**

I got a table that contains price for some 1 000 000 articles. The articles got a uniques ID-number but the table contains prices from multiple stores. Thus if two stores got the same article the uniques ID will not be unique for the table.

**Table Structure**

table articles

id INT

price IN

store VARCHAR(40)

**Daily use**

Except for queries using the ID-number by users I need to run daily updates where data from csv-files insert/update each article in the table. The choosen procedure is to try to select an article and then perform either an insert or an update.

**Question**

With this in mind, which key should I choose?

Here are some solutions that Ive been considering:

- `FULLTEXT` index of the fields `isbn` and `store`
- Add a field with a value `generated by` `isbn` and `store` that is set as `PRIMARY` key
- One table per store and use `isbn` as `PRIMARY` key

Comment: Can you post the structure of your table please?

Comment: Sounds like you need to restructure your tables.  You should only have one row per item.  If it has multiple prices these would be reflected in a separate table, which could be a many-to-many between item and store.

Comment: @John OK, and then use an e.g. autoincremented id as key there, but how can I increase the performans since the update procedure needs to go through 1M articles by isbn and update most of them, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a compound primary key consisting of the store ID and the article ID - that'll give you a unique primary key for each item on a per-store basis and you don't need a separate field for it (assuming the store id and article id are already in the table).

Ideally you should have 3 tables... something like:

```
article
--------------------------------------------
id | isbn | ... etc ...


store
--------------------------------------------
id | description | ... etc ...


pricelist
--------------------------------------------
article_id | store_id | price | ... etc ...
```

With the `PRIMARY KEY` for `pricelist` being a compound key made up of `article_id` and `store_id`.

**EDIT :** (updated to incorporate an answer from the comment)

Even on a million rows the `UPDATE` *should* be OK (for a certain definition of OK, it might still take a little while with 1 million+ rows) since the `article_id` and `store_id` comprise the `PRIMARY KEY` - they'll **both** be indexed.

You'll just need to write your query so that it's along the lines of:

```
UPDATE pricelist SET price = {$fNewPrice} 
WHERE article_id = {$iArticleId} 
AND store_id =` '{$sStoreId}'
```

Though you may want to consider converting the `PRIMARY KEY` in the `store` table (`store.id` - and therefore also `pricelist.store_id` in the `pricelist` table) to either an **unsigned INT** or something like **CHAR(30)**.

Whilst **VARCHAR** is more efficient when it comes to disk space it has a couple of drawbacks:

1: MySQL isn't too keen on updating VARCHAR values and it can make the indexes bloat a bit so you may need to occasionally run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on it (I've found this on an *order_header* table before).

2: Any (MyISAM) table with non-fixed length fields (such as **VARCHAR**) will have to have a **DYNAMIC** row format which is slightly less efficient when it comes to querying it - there's more information about that on this SO post: [MySQL Row Format: Difference between fixed and dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147315/mysql-row-format-difference-between-fixed-and-dynamic)

Comment: Since I need to run updates on +1M posts in e.g. pricelist. Should I then check for the composite key of article_id and store_id? Will that create any performance issue? My testing is that it works fine searching with a PRIMARY key but is too demanding searching by a non-key.

Comment: It should be OK since both the `article_id` AND `store_id` will be indexed (as they make up the primary key) - you'll just need to write your query so that it's along the lines of `UPDATE pricelist SET price = {$fNewPrice} WHERE article_id = {$iArticleId} AND store_id = '{$sStoreId}'` -- I'll update the answer since there's a couple of provisos :)

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes should be aligned with your queries. Certainly there should be a primary key on the articles table using STORE and ID - but the order in which they are declared will affect performance - depending on the data in the related tables and the queries applied. Indeed the simplest solution might be PRIMARY KEY(STORE, ID) **and** UNIQUE KEY(ID, STORE) along with foreign key constraints on the two fields.

i.e. since it makes NO SENSE to call this table 'articles', I'll use the same schema as CD001:

```
CREATE TABLE pricelist (
    id INT NOT NULL ,
    price INT,
    store VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(store,id),
    UNIQUE KEY rlookup (id, store)
    CONSTRAINT id FOREIGN KEY articles.id,
    CONSRAINT store FOREIGN KEY store.name
);
```

Which also entails having a primary key on store using name.

The difference between checking a key based on a single column and one based on 2 columns is negligible - and normalising your database properyl will save you a LOT of pain.