# Make MySQL table FIXED by splitting TEXT field into chunks of type CHAR(255)

Tags: mysql, optimization, split

FIXED MySQL table has well-known performance advantages over DYNAMIC table.

There is a table `tags` with only one `description` TEXT field. An idea is to split this field into 4-8 CHAR(255) fields. For INSERT/UPDATE queries just divide description into chunks (PHP function `str_split()`). That will make table FIXED.

Have anybody practiced this technique? Is it worth it?

Comment: I think this is true for MyISAM only. See a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/147337/2091410) and also read the references cited in the accepted answer.

Comment: Those "well known performance advantages" with MyISAM can evaporate, when those fixed length rows occupy a lot more memory than variable length records. If fewer rows fit in memory, that may cause additional i/o, and it can actually degrade performance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's **not** worth  messing up your data model for a performance gain that you aren't even sure it exists. And even if there *was* a performance gain (which I really doubt) that must be extremely high in order to justify such an horrible model.

Comment: It is not worth it. Just don't use MyISAM. It's slower, broken, and antiquated. It is receiving no improvements, and it's likely to be deprecated within the next couple of MySQL versions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is done, but where it is done I have only seen it done for historical reasons, such as a particular client-server model that requires it, or for legacy reports where the segments are de facto fields in the layout.

The examples I have seen where for free form text entries (remarks, notes, contact log) in insurance/collections applications and the like where formatting on a printed report was important or there was a need to avoid any confusion in post post processing to dress the format where multiple platforms are involved. (\r\n vs \n and EBCDIC vertical tabs).

So not generally for space/performance/recovery purposes.

If the row is "mostly" this field, a alternative would be to create a row for each segment and add a low-range sequence number to the key.

In this way you would have only 1 row for short values and up to 8 for long. Consider your likely statistics.

Caveats :

Always be acutely aware of MySQL indexes dropping trailing spaces. Concatenating these should take this into account if used in an index.

This is not a recommendation, but "tags" sounds like a candidate for a single varchar field for full text indexing. If the data is so important that forensic recovery is a requirement, then normalising the model to store the tags in a separate table may be another way to go.