# Performance benefit in using correct data types

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

Is there any performance benefit in using the exact data types needed for a column? Or is it just storage optimisation?

For example, I'm creating a users table and I know for certainty that there will only be 200 users in total. When I'm manipulating the data in the the server, doing some select/update/insert/delete, is there any performance difference between using `TINYINT - UN` for the users_id column or using just `INT`?

The same applies to the user's name. I know, for now, that the user with the longest name length is 48, but I don't know if in the future there won't be a new user inserted in the table with a name with 65 characters in length. Is there any performance benefit in reserving only the needed lenght, for now, using `VARCHAR(48)` or can I avoid having to check constantly the column allowed length for each new user and use just `VARCHAR(255)`?

Comment: Narrower rows -> More rows can fit in memory -> Better performance

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question! First you ask if there is any performance benefit in using the exact data types [as opposed to variable length ones], then you ask if it is better to use tinyint or int (both are fixed lenght data types) or varchar(48) or varchar(255) (both of them are variable length data types). The 1st question makes sense, the 2nd question does not, since whether you would like to have over 1 billion users or would like to allow names up to 255 characters is really up to you.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli this is not always true.

Comment: fyi, `varchar` columns occupy the amount of data you store in it plus a length . i.e. set it to some convenient maximum (255) so that you don't need to change the database if you make the data larger. so, varchar(48) vs varchar(64) will not save any data or processing. It is all explained here: [12.8 Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html)

Comment: There is a case where `VARCHAR(255)` hurts relative to `VARCHAR(48)`.  In a complex select, there may have to be a "temp" table.  This could be either MEMORY (faster) or MyISAM (unlimited size).  In building the tmp MEMORY table, varchars become chars, so (255) utf8 takes 767 bytes.  If the MEMORY temp table gets "too big", it is converted to a slower MyISAM table.

Comment: @Shadow - I'm with Joe, with a slight modification:  Narrower rows --> not worse performance.  Do you have a counter example?

Comment: @RickJames this SO topic sums it up pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147315/mysql-row-format-difference-between-fixed-and-dynamic

Comment: Yes, "FIXED" _MyISAM_ rows _can_ run faster.  However, I have encountered very few real-life use cases there they actually help.  MyISAM is all but deprecated.

Comment: @RickJames I think you should re-read the linked topic because it has some nice links about innodb storage engine as well. Moreover, you wrote you did encounter a few use cases where this actually helped, which means that you should not have asked for counter examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little advantage in either case.

For the number, you do gain a slight performance advantage.  Typically, integers are 4 and a tinyint is 1 byte.  So, if you have multiple smaller fields, then your records will be smaller.  Smaller records then imply fewer data pages and ultimately slightly faster queries.  This shows up when you start to have lots of records.

For the `varchar`, you don't even have that advantage.  Both `varchar(48)` and `varchar(255)` occupy the same amount of space (there is one addition byte for lengths greater than 255).  The values determine the space for this data type.

In other cases, it can make a big difference.  In particular, storing dates as the native format is usually important, both to take advantage of date/time functions and to make better use of indexes.