# Understanding MySQL MyISAM ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a MyISAM table with 1600 columns of integer type only (tinyint, smallint, mediumint, int). The table has 800k rows.

`ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` => binary file size = 3GB (= expected value)

`ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` => binary file size = 200MB

Why does the file size change since all the columns *(please don't question me on the column count)* have fixed lengths?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Row Format: Difference between fixed and dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147315/mysql-row-format-difference-between-fixed-and-dynamic)

Comment: @nbk None of the answers there explain why it would be different with no variable-length columns.

Comment: Have you done `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on both versions of the table? You may be seeing space taken up by deleted rows.

Comment: @nbk No, I already read this answer before posting my question. My question is about the physical binary file sizes which should be the same in both `ROW_FORMAT` since all the columns have fixed lengths

Comment: @Barmar there are no deleted rows

Comment: How are you determining the file size? Unix files have a length and number of blocks. The latter can be less than `length/blocksize` if there are zero blocks, because they're not stored explicitly on disk. So if you have lots of contiguous all-zero rows, that might get optimized out of disk space.

Comment: @Barmar expected file size = (sum of column lengths) * (row count) = 3GB

Comment: I was asking what ACTUAL file size you're using. Size in bytes or size in disk blocks?

Comment: @Barmar I'm using the size in bytes, which matches the size given by phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero values are optimized in dynamic format. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/dynamic-format.html):

> Each row is preceded by a bitmap that indicates which columns contain the empty string (for string columns) or zero (for numeric columns). This does not include columns that contain NULL values. If a string column has a length of zero after trailing space removal, or a numeric column has a value of zero, it is marked in the bitmap and not saved to disk. Nonempty strings are saved as a length byte plus the string contents.

So the size difference suggests that most of the values in your table are zero.

Comment: Accepted. Most of the values are zero indeed.

Comment: Another reason to eschew `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` !